# How do I apply int to every string using map and lambda in python?

Tags: python, lambda

I want to avoid doing ugly int to each element in a list.

```
dictionary[l[0]] = [(int(l[1])+ int(l[2])+ int(l[3]))/3] #avg score of 3 grades
    sub1 += int(l[1])
    sub2 += int(l[2])
    sub3 += int(l[3])
```

The list l has 4 elements, 0 to 3 indexes. I need to apply int starting with the 1st-element, not 0th element.

I'm trying to write something like:

```
   map lambda x: int(x) for i in l[1:]
```

Do I need lambda here, since map can already do the job?

Comment: You should use float instead of int for computing the average (at least in Python 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` calls a function on each element of a list. Since `int` is a function you can use

```
map(int, lst)
```

directly.

Lambda functions just give you more flexibility, say if you wanted to do:

```
map(lambda x: 5*int(x), lst)
```

A more Pythonic way to do the above would be to use list comprehensions

```
[int(x) for x in lst]
[5*int(x) for x in lst]
```

In Python3 `map` returns a generator. If you wish to have a list, you'd want to do:

```
list(map(int, lst))
```

Comment: does map return smth? Do I need to do lst = map(int, lst)?

Comment: @ERJAN map() returns a map object. You need to convert it into a list. For example: list2 = list(map(int, list1))

Comment: IMHO `int` is better characterized as a callable, not a function.

Comment: Thanks, @VPfB, that might well be right. What is a callable and how does it differ from a function?

Comment: @Richard Callable is a general term for classes, class methods, functions, lambdas and possibly other objects that can be called https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls . Functions are defined with `def` keyword.